# Prefix html before radiobutton (input field)

Tags: 7, forms, input-formats

I'm looking to insert some extra html before an input radio button. This is my html now:

```
<div id="edit-field-geslacht-und" class="form-radios">
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-geslacht-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-female" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="female" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-geslacht-und-female">Female</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-geslacht-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-male" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="male" checked="checked" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-geslacht-und-male">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-geslacht-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-other" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="other" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-geslacht-und-other">Other (transgender...)</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to add the following html before every radio input:

```
<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -28px;"></span>
```

But how can I do this?

**UPDATE**:

I've tried to do it with [theme_form_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) function and now have this:

```
function theme_form_element($variables)
{
    if($variables['element']['#type'] == 'radio')
    {
        dump($variables);
    }
}
```

My dump shows me this array:

```
array (size=1)
  'element' => 
    array (size=27)
      '#type' => string 'radio' (length=5)
      '#title' => string 'Female' (length=6)
      '#return_value' => string 'female' (length=6)
      '#default_value' => string 'male' (length=4)
      '#attributes' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      '#parents' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'field_geslacht' (length=14)
          1 => string 'und' (length=3)
      '#id' => string 'edit-field-geslacht-und-female' (length=30)
      '#ajax' => null
      '#weight' => float 0.001
      '#input' => boolean true
      '#process' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ajax_process_form' (length=17)
      '#theme' => string 'radio' (length=5)
      '#theme_wrappers' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'form_element' (length=12)
      '#title_display' => string 'after' (length=5)
      '#pre_render' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ctools_dependent_pre_render' (length=27)
      '#after_build' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'conditional_fields_element_after_build' (length=38)
      '#defaults_loaded' => boolean true
      '#tree' => boolean true
      '#array_parents' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'field_geslacht' (length=14)
          1 => string 'und' (length=3)
          2 => string 'female' (length=6)
      '#processed' => boolean true
      '#required' => boolean false
      '#name' => string 'field_geslacht[und]' (length=19)
      '#value' => string 'male' (length=4)
      '#ajax_processed' => boolean false
      '#sorted' => boolean true
      '#after_build_done' => boolean true
      '#children' => string '<input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-female" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="female" class="form-radio" />' (length=119)
```

I've tried to change the `#children` variable and add my html before it. But when I do that no element on my page is showing ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [theme_radio](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radio/7) function in your own theme :

```
function mytheme_radio($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'radio';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name','#return_value' => 'value'));

  if (isset($element['#return_value']) && $element['#value'] !== FALSE && $element['#value'] == $element['#return_value']) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));

  if ($its_my_field) {
     return '<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -28px;"></span><input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  }
  else {
     return '</span><input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  }
```

Maybe try with the more generic function [theme_form_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7).

Make sure to add conditions to only affect the form or the element you need like in the example written above.

Comment: I've tried to do it with theme_form_element but didn't work, updated my topic. Could you take a look,

Comment: Can you give me the entire code of your theme_form_element function please ?

Comment: You should have something like this : `$output .= ' ' . $prefix . '<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -28px;"></span>' . $element['#children'] . $suffix . "\n";` and `return $output` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery selector -

```
    <html>
    <head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
jQuery( "input[type=radio]" ).before( '<span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -28px;"></span>' );
});    
</script></head>
<body>
<div id="edit-field-geslacht-und" class="form-radios">
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-geslacht-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-female" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="female" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-geslacht-und-female">Female</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-geslacht-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-male" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="male" checked="checked" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-geslacht-und-male">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-geslacht-und">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-geslacht-und-other" name="field_geslacht[und]" value="other" class="form-radio">  
        <label class="option" for="edit-field-geslacht-und-other">Other (transgender...)</label>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```